# Tips to improve MapReduce Job performance in Hadoop

Tags: performance, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I have 100 mapper and 1 reducer running in a job. How to improve the job performance?

As per my understanding: Use of combiner can improve the performance to great extent. But what else we need to configure to improve the jobs performance?

Answer (score 4):

With the limited data in this question ( Input file size, HDFS block size, Average map processing time, Number of Mapper slots & Reduce slots in cluster etc.), we can't suggest tips.

But there are some general guidelines to improve the performance.

1. If each task takes less than **30-40 seconds**, reduce the number of tasks
2. If a job has more than *1TB of input*, consider increasing the block size of the input dataset to *256M or even 512M* so that the number of tasks will be smaller.
3. So long as each task runs for at least *30-40 seconds*, increase the number of mapper tasks to some multiple of the number of mapper slots in the cluster
4. Number of reduce tasks per a job should be equal to or a bit less than the number of reduce slots in the cluster.

Some more tips :

1. Configure the cluster properly with *right diagnostic tools*
2. Use *compression* when you are writing intermediate data to disk
3. *Tune number of Map & Reduce tasks* as per above tips
4. Incorporate *Combiner* wherever it is appropriate
5. Use Most *appropriate data type*s for rendering Output ( Do not use `LongWritable` when range of output values are in `Integer` range. `IntWritable` is right choice in this case)
6. Reuse `Writables`
7. Have *right profiling tools*

Have a look at this [cloudera](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/12/7-tips-for-improving-mapreduce-performance/) article for some more tips.