# Hadoop Resource management

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, cloudera

I have a 12 node cluster and I am running a yarn architecture. It seems that my nodes are busy most of the time and many times job fails. How can I check the usage of the resources at any point of time? 
Also is there any method to set a limited resource to a user for eg: if a user submits a job he should be given only 25gb of memory and 12 cores.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to monitor the cluster.

If you are using Cloudera distribution then you can go to Cloudera Manager to monitor and manage the resources

If you are using Hortonworks distribution then you can go to Ambari web interface to monitor and manage the resources

If you are not using any distributions then clusters will be managed using Ganglia or Nagios web interface

Even if you do not have any of these you can go to resource manager web interface which typically runs on http://:8088. 8088 is default port number, it can be customized and you can get that information from yarn-site.xml

If your organization does not provide access to the web interfaces you can use commands such as `yarn application --list` and `mapred job --list` to see what is going on in the cluster

It is little tedious to monitor actual usage. You should know linux commands to monitor and develop shell scripts.

> Also is there any method to set a limited resource to a user for eg: if a user submits a job he should be given only 25gb of memory and 12 cores.

Yes, you need to use queues and pools concept of schedulers embedded in Yarn. There are 3 types of scheduler FIFO, Capacity and Fair. FIFO should not be used in any of the clusters, it is mainly for development. You need to understand capacity and fair scheduler and set the limits.

Comment: I have access to cloudera manager, name node and resource manager web UI

Comment: Then you can go to Cloudera Manager and monitor the CPU, memory and I/O usage. You can start at cluster level and drill down to individual hosts. By going to resource manager UI, you can monitor current running jobs.

Comment: Thank you Durga. Any Idea about the second part of the question?

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that my nodes are busy most of the time and many times job fails

You can implement some generic performance tuning guidelines to improve the thorughput. Have a look at this post : [Tips to improve MapReduce Job performance in Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34241198/tips-to-improve-mapreduce-job-performance-in-hadoop/34242606#34242606) , [cloudera article](http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/cdh_ig_yarn_tuning.html) and [Map reduce performance aticle](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/12/7-tips-for-improving-mapreduce-performance/)

> Also is there any method to set a limited resource to a user for eg: if a user submits a job he should be given only 25gb of memory and 12 cores.

Adding to Durga's answer,

**Fair scheduling** is a method of assigning resources to applications such that all apps get, on average, an equal share of resources over time. Hadoop NextGen is capable of scheduling multiple resource types.

By default, the Fair Scheduler bases scheduling fairness decisions only on memory. It can be configured to schedule with both memory and CPU, using the notion of Dominant Resource Fairness developed by Ghodsi.

The scheduler organizes apps further into “queues”, and shares resources fairly between these queues. `By default, all users share a single queue, named “default”. If an app specifically lists a queue in a container resource request, the request is submitted to that queue. It is also possible to assign queues based on the user name` included with the request through configuration.

e.g.

```
<user name="sample_user">
    <maxRunningApps>30</maxRunningApps>
  </user>
  <userMaxAppsDefault>5</userMaxAppsDefault>
```

The **CapacityScheduler** is designed to run Hadoop applications as a shared, multi-tenant cluster in an operator-friendly manner while maximizing the throughput and the utilization of the cluster.

Traditionally each organization has it own private set of compute resources that have sufficient capacity to meet the organization’s SLA under peak or near peak conditions. This generally leads to poor average utilization and overhead of managing multiple independent clusters, one per each organization

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.queue-mappings</name>

  <value>u:user1:queue1,g:group1:queue2,u:%user:%user,u:user2:%primary_group</value>
  <description>
    Here, <user1> is mapped to <queue1>, <group1> is mapped to <queue2>, 
    maps users to queues with the same name as user, <user2> is mapped 
    to queue name same as <primary group> respectively. The mappings will be 
    evaluated from left to right, and the first valid mapping will be used.
  </description>
</property>
```

Have a look at [Fair scheduler](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/FairScheduler.html) and [Capacity scheduler](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html)

Comment: I am using fair scheduler. right now my jobs are failing due to the insufficient memory or cpu (I am not sure). How can I fix this problem

Comment: Can you post the failure message?  If you think CPU or Memory is not sufficient, add some more nodes to cluster. If you are constrained by resources, look at some of the tips posted in my answer, which are generic guidelines.