# Ideas to improve the performance Java MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am currently working on Java MapReduce.We have functionality where we read each line in Java Mapper class and then do some validate against DB.The issue is in DB we have around 5 million records.
The input file to Mapper may also contains records @1 million.
So its like for each line we scan 8 million records.
This process is taking very huge time.
Can anybody suggest if we have any better way to improve the performance.

Running multiple maps, parallel execution(though Hadoop Java Map reduce itself does this) but looking at the current time I think it should not take this much time
May be I am missing any configuration for the Java Map reduce etc.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand, but from what I read you are comparing each individual input line (1 million) against the existing DB (5 million). That would mean you may would evaluate 5e12 combinations of lines. -- If that is correct, the obvious solution is to find a way to not need to evaluate all combinations.

Comment: Have a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34241198/tips-to-improve-mapreduce-job-performance-in-hadoop/34242606#34242606

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest not to validate rows in Java code, but to filter unwanted rows using more restrictive SQL WHERE clause instead. It should give you couple of % in performance depending on rows count difference.

I would also suggest you to interest in [Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org) which is way faster Hadoop overlay.

Comment: Let me give more info, for each line from input, the validation is where that person exists in HBase by using a unique hash. though it takes 5 milliseconds, but for a total records it is taking more time