# How to optimize Mapreduce Job

Tags: java, hadoop, optimization, mapreduce, emr

So I have a job that does in mapper computing. With each task taking about .08 seconds, a 360026 line file will take about 8 hours to just do this. If it was done on one node. File sizes will generally be about the size of 1-2 block sizes (often 200 MB or less).

Assuming the in code is optimized, is there anyway to mess with the settings? Should I be using a smaller block size for example? I currently am using AWS EMR, with c4.large instances and autoscaling on YARN, but it only went up to 4 extra task nodes, as the load wasn't too high. Even though YARN memory wasn't too high, it still took over 7 hours to complete (which is way to long).

Comment: This post may be useful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34241198/tips-to-improve-mapreduce-job-performance-in-hadoop/34242606#34242606

Comment: @Ravindrababu Thank you, there are some great tips in there, and i have read Cloudera's post! So they only is, in my case, each row must undergo a call to an api, so i think i need more nodes but not bigger ones in order to just parallelize it. The computation isn't difficult, but I was only getting one task since the block size was so small and the task would take hours.